# Trouble installing packages on Xubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, xubuntu

I'm looking to install `eclipse`, and I'm running into some issues:

- Ubuntu Software center starts the download OK, but has a connection issue mid-way through. (I'm on a stable office network, and it's not dropping any packets from my `ping 8.8.8.8` tests)
- Running `sudo apt-get install eclipse` gives me:

  ```
  sh-4.3$ sudo apt-get install eclipse
  [sudo] password for alex: 
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
    libmysqlcppconn7 libodbc1 libvsqlitepp3 mysql-utilities
    python-mysql.connector python-pyodbc
  Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
  The following extra packages will be installed:
    binfmt-support ca-certificates-java default-jdk default-jre
    default-jre-headless eclipse-jdt eclipse-pde eclipse-platform
    eclipse-platform-data eclipse-rcp fastjar fonts-dejavu-extra
    icedtea-7-jre-jamvm jarwrapper libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni
    libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common
    libcommons-compress-java libcommons-dbcp-java libcommons-pool-java
    libdb-java libdb-je-java libdb5.3-java libdb5.3-java-jni libecj-java
    libequinox-osgi-java libfelix-bundlerepository-java
    libfelix-gogo-command-java libfelix-gogo-runtime-java
    libfelix-gogo-shell-java libfelix-osgi-obr-java libfelix-shell-java
    libfelix-utils-java libgail18 libgconf2-4 libgeronimo-jta-1.1-spec-java
    libglade2-0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnomecanvas2-0
    libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0
    libgnomevfs2-common libice-dev libicu4j-4.4-java libicu4j-java libidl-common
    libidl0 libjetty8-java libjtidy-java libkxml2-java liblucene2-java
    libnss3-1d liborbit-2-0 liborbit2 libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev
    libswt-cairo-gtk-3-jni libswt-glx-gtk-3-jni libswt-gnome-gtk-3-jni
    libswt-gtk-3-java libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni libtomcat7-java
    libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxt-dev
    libxz-java openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless sat4j
    tzdata-java x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev
    xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
  Suggested packages:
    libbonobo2-bin libcommons-dbcp-java-doc libdb5.3-java-gcj ecj
    libecj-java-gcj libfelix-bundlerepository-java-doc
    libfelix-gogo-command-java-doc libfelix-gogo-runtime-java-doc
    libfelix-gogo-shell-java-doc libfelix-osgi-obr-java-doc
    libfelix-shell-java-doc libfelix-utils-java-doc libgeronimo-jta-java-doc
    libgnomevfs2-bin libgnomevfs2-extra gamin fam gnome-mime-data libice-doc
    jetty8 libjetty8-java-doc libjtidy-java-doc libsm-doc libswt-gtk-3-java-gcj
    tomcat7 libxcb-doc libxt-doc openjdk-7-demo openjdk-7-source visualvm
    sun-java6-fonts fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho ttf-wqy-microhei
    ttf-wqy-zenhei ttf-telugu-fonts ttf-oriya-fonts ttf-kannada-fonts
    ttf-bengali-fonts
  The following NEW packages will be installed:
    binfmt-support ca-certificates-java default-jdk default-jre
    default-jre-headless eclipse eclipse-jdt eclipse-pde eclipse-platform
    eclipse-platform-data eclipse-rcp fastjar fonts-dejavu-extra
    icedtea-7-jre-jamvm jarwrapper libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni
    libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common
    libcommons-compress-java libcommons-dbcp-java libcommons-pool-java
    libdb-java libdb-je-java libdb5.3-java libdb5.3-java-jni libecj-java
    libequinox-osgi-java libfelix-bundlerepository-java
    libfelix-gogo-command-java libfelix-gogo-runtime-java
    libfelix-gogo-shell-java libfelix-osgi-obr-java libfelix-shell-java
    libfelix-utils-java libgail18 libgconf2-4 libgeronimo-jta-1.1-spec-java
    libglade2-0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnomecanvas2-0
    libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0
    libgnomevfs2-common libice-dev libicu4j-4.4-java libicu4j-java libidl-common
    libidl0 libjetty8-java libjtidy-java libkxml2-java liblucene2-java
    libnss3-1d liborbit-2-0 liborbit2 libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev
    libswt-cairo-gtk-3-jni libswt-glx-gtk-3-jni libswt-gnome-gtk-3-jni
    libswt-gtk-3-java libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni libtomcat7-java
    libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxt-dev
    libxz-java openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless sat4j
    tzdata-java x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev
    xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
  0 upgraded, 88 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
  Need to get 55.9 MB/223 MB of archives.
  After this operation, 304 MB of additional disk space will be used.
  Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
  Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main openjdk-7-jre-headless amd64 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1
    404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
  Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main openjdk-7-jre-headless amd64 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1
    404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
  Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main openjdk-7-jre amd64 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1
    404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
  Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1
    404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
  Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main icedtea-7-jre-jamvm amd64 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1
    404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
  E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

  E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/openjdk-7-jre_7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

  E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/openjdk-7-jdk_7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

  E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/icedtea-7-jre-jamvm_7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

  E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
  ```

  - When I try to run `sudo apt-get update`, I get:

    ```
    sh-4.3$ sudo apt-get update
    E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/htpp could not be found.
    ```
  - `htpp` seems like a typo in some sort of configuration file, but I'm not sure. I should note this system has been used by many before me, and this is my first use of it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**edit:** `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: @pilot6 Thanks for that edit. For some reason the code syntax highlighting button wasn't working properly :/

Comment: `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https` run the command and then update

Comment: Please add output of `cat /etc/sources.list` to your question.

Comment: please edit and add output of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Forgot that! done :)

Comment: Any change in error using `sudo apt-get update` after trying my first comment

Comment: "apt-transport-https is already the newest version."

Comment: @Ravan did that edit, and there's no change, I'm afraid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28898/discussion-between-ravan-and-xalexownzx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was from a typo in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list`. Changing `htpp` to `http` fixed this issue.

Comment: You would probably better have made a symbolic link called htpp to the original http file, but probably it does not matter much. Finding the wrong script/config that uses it would have been the best fix though.

Comment: I `grep`ed by entire file system and found the conflicting file :)